# How to Convert a normal class.cs to DataModel.dbml

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have 20 class.cs with x00s properties for my old project 
and now i want to use EntityFramework 

but I dont want to rewrite all this classes from begin 

i just want to convert this class to DataModel.dbml or use some thing like add Existing Item
and I tried  creat class with same name and copy the code inside them but the editor clear them after saving

how can i do that ?

Comment: A DBML file is for LinqToSql the evuivelent in EF is an EDMX file. However with EF you can develop using code first, which does not require any kind of DB model file. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/01/tutorial-series-updated-for-entity-framework-6-code-first-with-mvc-5.aspx

Comment: soo can i creat database from my normal class ??

Comment: Yes, you can use any classes, if you use the fluent API you do not need to alter them in any way at all.

Comment: thank you BenRobinson but i dont know how can i do that?
any url or articl ?

Comment: Follow the link in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty of resources regarding Plain Old CLR Objects and Entity Framework code first model on the web.

- [ADO.NET EF 4.0: Working with Plain Old CLR Objects (POCO) Classes](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=725)
- [Code First step by step tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx)

But the gist of it is:

1. Entity Framework >4.0 supports POCO types that don’t need to inherit from a base class or 
   implement any interfaces to get persistence. There is also no need for metadata or mapping 
   attributes on type members, so *you can use your existing code as simple entity classes*.
2. **An EDMX file that contains the conceptual model is still required**. Add a new ADO.NET Entity Data Model to the project.
3. Using the toolbox, drag entities and associations from the toolbox and design the conceptual model. Simply make sure that the *names on your POCO classes match the names of your conceptual entities*.
4. Add entity keys as you would add primary keys in a db. Add associations like foreign keys in a db.
5. In Solution Explorer, click the EDMX file and then, in the Properties window, **clear the Custom    Tool property to turn off the automatic generation of .NET classes for your conceptual model**.
6. Right click edmx design area and select '*Generate database from model*'. DDL will be produced. Run that to create your db.
7. Make sure your POCO classes and POCO edmx model are *in a separate assembly*.
8. Create your custom `ObjectContext` derived data context with `ObjectSet<T>` members like [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/06/01/conventions-for-code-first.aspx). Newer EF releases use `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` and `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<T>` instead.
9. You can use dbml too (Linq To Sql classes instead of EF), but you still need to generate your model from scratch, like you'd do with EF.